# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list VM874:10

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Guys can you tell me what's the problem in my code below?

```
//this code below is showing an error
First.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var input = document.getElementById("lastname")
 //i will change the class in function below that's why i am changing it back for some reason
     input.class === "margin5" ? input.class = "margin5 m-47" : console.log("false")
     input.value = "what ever value i want"
     changvaluE()
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `//`, not `\\` for comment. Those two are completely different. Please consider formatting your question for clarity. I don't understand what the question is, and the code is very badly formatted.

Comment: Aside from that, you are missing the closing `)` at the bottom of this code for `First.addEventListener( ...`

Comment: Install a linter on your IDE, it will point out the errors

Comment: @J.Ko Thank you for your time but that wasn't the real problem

Comment: @epascarello thank you for your time too and i will download IDE Later

Comment: @EdLucas Thank You for your time that was the problem
can you post you answer please instead of commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reformatting the code, it appears that you are missing the closing ')' for `First.addEventListener(`.